# Windows Services Framework?

Tags: c#, windows-services

Are there any good frameworks or templates for developing Windows Services? I generally don't write windows services and hoping someone has shared their expertise via an api or example project.

I am working on a project with the following requirements:

  **A windows service that:**
- performs 1..many independently scheduled tasks
- reports on the success or failure of these tasks via email/log/sms/??
- allows adding/removal of tasks
- allows changing of schedules

**UPDATE**

marc_s answer reminded me of [this](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2005/05/01/Create-a-NET-Agent.aspx?Page=1) 2005 Visual Studio Magazine article by Luther Miller that I read.

Comment: C# is preferred. Definitely willing to look at non C# solutions too.

Comment: What do you mean by framework/template? You want to work within other code and just use their APi?

Comment: Wouldn't the windows task scheduler do for all of these things?

Comment: @jimplode - API or example project. Something more than the Visual Studio Windows Service project.

Comment: [Topshelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) is "an easy service hosting framework for building Windows services using .NET"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but for the occasional Googler coming across this, as I have:

[Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) is a nice Windows Services framework.

Creating Windows Services using the standard Windows Service Template in Visual Studio is simple enough, you don't really need any special framework. However, in VS Express you may not have the winservice template and then Topshelf makes it quite easy using the Windows -> Console Application project template.

There is no single framework that will provide all the requirements listed in the original question, but here are some suggestions:

> - many independently scheduled tasks
> - allows adding/removal of tasks
> - allows changing of schedules

You're probably pretty much on your own here, but it's easy enough to accomplish with timer(s) and simple configuration in your App.config.  Or, if you want to be fancy, using dependency injection or a plugin mechanism, maybe using MEF.

> - reports on the success or failure of these tasks via email/log/sms/??

Look at log4net or NLog. Topshelf has support for both.

(Having used Windows Workflow Foundation (WF), I'm not convinced at all by the WF-related answers to this question. I would appreciate if anyone is able to provide references to reputable sample apps that show how WF could possibly address any of these requirements in the original question.)

Comment: This is the most apt answer to the original question - like you've said, TopShelf (https://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) looks awesome and that combined with Quartz.NET + NLog would pretty much cover all bases.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of software, there's no need for anything other than the .NET base class library.

I found this two-part article very useful and enlightening, especially considering your requirement to "performs 1..many independently scheduled tasks....":

- [Creating an Extensible Windows Service (Part 1)](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/021007.htm)
- [Creating an Extensible Windows Service (Part 2)](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/021015.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I make no promises, but this sounds like a candidate for using [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a scheduler kind of thing that you are looking for, then you may want to look at [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). This is an open source job scheduling system. It would be easier to use an existing tool rather than rewriting one from scratch (unless it is for academic purposes).

Answer (score 0):

The framework is .Net! :-) WCF for the communication and WF for the implementation. In .Net 4 these come together as a WCF Workflow Service.

Comment: Sorry, but Workflow Services (WF + WCF) are not the same thing as Windows Services :-) WCF is for things like Web Services, and is typically hosted in IIS. Windows Services are something else. An example of a Windows Service framework is [Topshelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf)

Comment: @G.Lombard, sorry, but you are a bit of a duckhead

Comment: You may be right :-) But it doesn't change the fact WCF and WF and Workflow Services have nothing to do about the original question ([Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6(v=vs.110).aspx)), or do you disagree?

Comment: @G.Lombard I disagree. I have personally built and deployed Windows Services built using WF and WCF. These technologies are not tied to the web. There are bindings such as NetTcpBinding, NetNamedPipes etc expressly for this purpose.

Comment: I have also used Windows Services, WCF and WF, so it's interesting that we disagree. I have also written Windows Services that do other things such as, say access a SQL db using EF or ADO.NET, so according to your reasoning, if I replied to this question on "Windows Services Framework" and suggested the guy looks at ADO.NET or Entity Framework and SQL Server (because I've written Windows Services that use SQL+EF), would you say that's a relevant answer worth an upvote? Anyway, it's pointless to debate this here in comments. I'm just confused why you were apparently so offended by my downvote.